# IBM Mobile First V 7.0

Tags: console, ibm-mobilefirst, analytics

I have an issue working in IBM Mobile First v7.0 Analytics console.
In analytics console the data was not loaded from mobile first server.but all data are stored in Worklight database...

The following configuration i did for my application and deployed in production server...

**Worklight.proerties file enable JNDI proerties**

wl.analytics.url=http://192.168.1.3:9080/analytics-service/data
wl.analytics.console.url=http://192.168.1.3:9080/analytics/console

Keep the **analytics.ear** file in my application foler...
C:\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\testserver\apps

**Server.xml**

```
<feature>jndi-1.0</feature>

</featureManager>
```

```
    <application location="analytics.ear"
    name="analytics-ear"
    type="ear">
  <application-bnd>
    <security-role name="worklightadmin">
       <user name="admin"/>
    </security-role>
    <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
       <user name="deployer"/>
    </security-role>
    <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
       <user name="monitor"/>
    </security-role>
    <security-role name="worklightoperator">
       <user name="operator"/>
    </security-role>
   </application-bnd>
     </application>
```

If I did any mistake, kindly anyone help me

Comment: Are there any errors in your logs?

Comment: Also make sure your basic registry is defined correctly. Can you log into your analytics console?

Comment: Hai Chevy Hungerford.. No errors in logs...I can log into analytics console by using basic registry username:admin and password:admin..  sorry for late reply..

Comment: I set worklight.properties file for analytics..
wl.analytics.logs.forward=true
wl.analytics.url=http://192.168.1.10:9080/analytics/data
wl.analytics.console.url=http://192.168.1.10:9080/analytics/console
wl.analytics.username=admin
wl.analytics.password=admin

is it correct ???

Comment: Make sure you have username set to, llke I have below.

Comment: hi chevy hungerford.. i set the following jndi properties in server.xml file

    <jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/wl.analytics.url" value="http://192.168.1.10:9080/analytics/data"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/wl.analytics.console.url" value="http://192.168.1.10:9080/analytics/console"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/wl.analytics.queues" value="1"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/wl.analytics.queue.size" value="1"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/wl.analytics.username" value="admin"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/wl.analytics.password" value="admin"/>

Thanks.....

Comment: In basicRegistry i set the following properties in server.xml

<basicRegistry>   
        <user name="WorklightRESTUser" password="MKPVK7cPcK7w"/>
    <user name="admin" password="admin"/>
  <user name="demo" password="demo"/  
    </basicRegistry>

Thanks

Comment: updated my answer below

Comment: yes chevy.. I checked role-names matched with names given in basic registery...

    <basicRegistry id="worklight" realm="worklightRealm">
       <user name="demo" password="demo"/>
  <user name="monitor" password="demo"/>
  <user name="deployer" password="demo"/>
  <user name="operator" password="demo"/>
  <user name="admin" password="admin"/>
    </basicRegistry>

Comment: <application location="analytics.ear" name="analytics-ear" type="ear">
  <application-bnd>
    <security-role name="worklightadmin">
       <user name="admin"/>
    </security-role>
    <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
       <user name="deployer"/>
    </security-role>
    <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
       <user name="monitor"/>
    </security-role>
    <security-role name="worklightoperator">
       <user name="operator"/>
    </security-role>
   </application-bnd>
</application>

Thanks.....

Comment: I followed the below link....

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/monitor/t_installing_op_analytics_liberty.html?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using security roles on your analytics console you need to send data with a username and password. Inside your server.xml for your Operations Console, you can set these username and password with the following JNDI properties:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="AppName/wl.analytics.username" value="admin"/>

<jndiEntry jndiName="AppName/wl.analytics.password" value="admin"/>
```

Also, make sure that your security roles an constraints match your server.xml to the WEB.xml in your analytics-service.war. Default is the security configuration below:

```
<security-constraint>
<security-role>
  <role-name>worklightadmin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>allAccess</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/data/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
  <role-name>worklightadmin</role-name>
  <role-name>worklightdeployer</role-name>
  <role-name>worklightmonitor</role-name>
  <role-name>worklightoperator</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
<user-data-constraint>
  <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

The role-names will need to match the names that you use in your basic registry.

Comment: Thanks Chevy Hungerford for your reply...i set the above username and password but still not work